# Python signal handlers and reentry

Tags: python, signals, reentrancy

Are [signal handlers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) in Python reentrant?

I have a signal handler for a timer that snapshots the stack many times a second - its a statistical profiler.  Can my signal handler re-enter if it takes too long?  If so, how can I guard it?

[My code](https://github.com/williame/will_profile):

```
import signal, time, traceback, threading

def start(interval=0.1):
    global _interval, _samples
    _samples = []
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM,_sample)
    signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL,interval,interval)

def stop():
    global _samples
    signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL,0,0)
    samples, _samples = _samples, []
    samples.append((time.time(),None,None,[]))
    return samples

def _sample(signo,frame):
    thread = threading.current_thread()
    row = (time.time(),thread.ident,thread.name,traceback.extract_stack(frame))
    if not _samples or row[1:] != _samples[-1][1:]: # new stack since last sample?
        _samples.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no way to block a signal in python. However, SIGALRM and friends cannot be stacked, so only one will be sent at a time. If you simply schedule the next timer event at the end of your handler function, you will not have to worry about reentrancy.

Comment: isn't there a race for setting a boolean, or calling a function to disable the alarm?

Comment: you mean for setting the `dump_stack` variable? Not really, since it can only be set from inside the signal handler. SIGALRM cannot be stacked (and it is non-repeating) , so the alarm handler does not need to be re-entrant. Also, because of this, you do not have to do anything to disable the alarm. You can simply schedule the next alarm at the end of your alarm handler.

Comment: I mean at the end of your `take_samples` function, __not__ at the end of your alarm handler.

Comment: alarm() cannot be scheduled for sub-second intervals, so is not any use for statistical profilers.  Your idea of take_samples() is not appropriate to statistical profiling either.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. In your question it was not specified that the statistical profiling had to be done on (semi) real time basis. This is not necessarily the case (e.g. for profiling memory usage it would not be).

Comment: My other observation still holds. The ITIMER_REAL can also not be stacked, so at the end of your handler you can simply restart the timer and not worry about reentrancy. I will rephrase my answer.

Comment: My understanding is that the callback can be in any thread, but only the main thread can call `signal.setitimer()`

Comment: It is the other way round. Any thread can call signal.setitimer(), but only the main thread can receive signals.

Comment: @Will, what did you end up with? I am curious whether you managed to solve this problem.

Comment: I put in a `Thread.lock` which I `acquire` non-blocking.  My understanding of CPython is that this is not necessary, but it seemed like a sensible precaution anyway.